# Printing numbers

Tags: c, loops, printf

I am writing a program to display as below

```
when n=3
1 2 3
7 8 9
4 5 6

when n=5
1 2 3 4 5
11 12 13 14 15
21 22 23 24 25
16 17 18 19 20
6 7 8 9 10
```

my program is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int n=5,r=1,c=1,i=1,mid=0;
    if(n%2==0)
      mid=(n/2);
    else 
      mid=(n/2)+1;
      printf("mid = %d\n",mid);
    while(r<=n)
    {
      while(c<=n)
      {
        printf("%d ",i);
        c++;
        i++;
      }
      r++;
      if(r<=mid)
       i=i+n;
      else
       i=i-(2*n);
      printf("\n");
      c=1;
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

when I give n=3, I am getting my expected output. but when I give n=5 I am getting as below

```
1 2 3 4 5
11 12 13 14 15
21 22 23 24 25
16 17 18 19 20
11 12 13 14 15
```

Could someone please help how to achieve expected output.

Comment: I edited my answer with more correction. Take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using you code the solution is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int n=5,r=1,c=1,i=1,mid=0;
    int maxRow = n;
    if(n%2==0){
      mid=(n/2);
      maxRow--;
    }
    else 
      mid=(n/2)+1;
      printf("mid = %d\n",mid);
    while(r<=maxRow)
    {
      while(c<=n)
      {
        printf("%d ",i);
        c++;
        i++;
      }
      r++;
      if(r<=mid)
       i=i+n;
      else if (r >= n)
        i=n+1;
      else
        i=i-((1+(r-mid))*n);

      printf("\n");
      c=1;
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see:

1. the `i=i-(2*n);` is changed. What you wrote wasn't generic, but specific for the `n=3` case.
2. I added `else if (r >= n)`.
3. Last thing you must use a specific variable for the outer while because of `n` must be decremented if `n` is even.

Some tips:

1. Give to your variables explanatory names
2. To make your code more readable declare variables 1 per line, if you want to init them.
3. Live empty lines between code chunks.

---

```
int main ()
{
    int squareDim=5;
    int row=1;
    int col=1;
    int valueToPrint=1;
    int mid=0;
    int maxRow = squareDim;

    if(squareDim%2==0)
    {
        mid=(squareDim/2);
        maxRow--;
    }
    else
    {
        mid=(squareDim/2)+1;
    }

    printf("mid = %d\n",mid);

    while(row<=maxRow)
    {
        while(col<=squareDim)
        {
            printf("%d ",valueToPrint);
            col++;
            valueToPrint++;
        }

        row++;

        if(row<=mid)
        {
            valueToPrint=valueToPrint+squareDim;
        }
        else if (row >= squareDim)
        {
            valueToPrint=squareDim+1;           
        }
        else
        {
            valueToPrint=valueToPrint-((1+(row-mid))*squareDim);
        }

        printf("\n");

        col=1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```